# Unable to run just this simple stream,... serde configuration needed?

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka-streams, spring-cloud-stream

Yes, I've read all docs I've found and try all alternatives on configuration, but just this simple example that should log a line does not work

(this is an Spring-Boot-2 app with spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams)

Kafka is storing an String value (null key)

my apllication.yaml

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        input:
          destination: 'myStreamTopic'
    output:
          producer.keySerde: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde'
      kafka:
        streams:
          binder:
            configuration:
              default.key.serde: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde'
              default.value.serde: 'org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$StringSerde'
            brokers:
              - 'ommited:9092'
              - 'ommited:9092'
              - 'ommited:9092'
            application-id: hack1
```

Just this simple code as a POC:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class HackatonApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
SpringApplication.run(HackatonApplication.class, args);
}

  @EnableBinding(KafkaStreamsProcessor.class)
  public static class LineProcessor {

    @StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
    public void process(KStream<?, String> line) {
      log.info("Received: {}", line);
    }

  }
```

and I am unable to get it running!

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'outputBindingLifecycle'; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Trying to invoke public abstract org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream.map(org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KeyValueMapper)  but no delegate has been set.
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:184) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:52) ~[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar!/:5.0.7.RELEASE]
    at

sorry if this is trivial but I have been hours searching, googling and trying to find a documented solution.

Comment: Hi. What happens if you replace the questionmark in your `process`parameters? --> `public void process(KStream<Object, String> line)`

Comment: Just the same error (btw thanks)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using the out of the box `KafkaStreamsProcessor` for binding which expects a single `KStream` as input and another `KStream` as output. If you are using this standard one, you must provide proper configuration for output binding (such as destination etc.). Then your method must return a `KStream` and you need to use the `SendTo` annotation on the spring side to bind. Something like below:

```
@StreamListener(Sink.INPUT)
@SendTo("output")
public KStream<?,String> process(KStream<?, String> line) {
    log.info("Received: {}", line);
    return line;
}
```

However, in your case, you can use a custom processor and use that for `EnableBinding`.

```
interface CustomKafkaStreamsProcessor {
        @Input("input")
        KStream<?, ?> input();
    }
```

and then use this with your binding. `@EnableBinding(CustomKafkaStreamsProcessor.class)`.

That way, you don't have to change the method to return something.

Comment: Perfect! What is strange to me is that there is not a "consume-only" processor (or there is?) in the library.... I know i can do with spring-starter-kafka but...

Comment: You can have consume only app in which this is basically a sink (i.e. the output is not going anywhere).